# stable particles in the W, Z infinite mass limit

Tags: particle-physics

Which particles do become stable, or increase notably its lifetime, when weak interactions are switched off?

Pretty sure neutron does, and charged pions surely too, and I'd guess all the particles whose main decay path is weak, but I am not sure if they are some exceptions here, particles whose electromagnetic or strong decay is not negligible.

Plus, I guess that it can be claimed that isospin becomes completely broken, so it is reasonable that the decay constants $f_\pi$ for $\pi^0$ and $\pi^\pm$ become completely unrelated. And so neither the $\pi^0$ not $\Sigma^0$ nor $J/\Psi$ should increase their lifetime, is this correct? It could be a bit subtle here.

Comment: That's a powerful switch you've got there.

Comment: The particles with strangeness, charmness, ecc... are going to decay only for weak decays, without weak interactions you would have a stable $K^0$. Another thing is that the top quark is going to decay before the hadronization thanks to the weak decay, without it you would have bounded states of the top. The $\pi^0$ decays for a $QED$-anomaly, the same for the $J/ \psi$ (QCD and QED), so they would be unaffected.

Comment: @Karozo good points. I saw the thing of the top, funny toppium. Was in doubt about $\pi^0$ because of the factor $f_\pi$

Comment: This plot can be helpful to separate different kinds of particles https://twitter.com/arivero/status/489907427324985345/photo/1